# Xamarin Upload php (laravel)

Tags: laravel, imagen, xamarin, upload

Buen dia tengan, mi problema es que desarrollo un app con xamarin forms, pero al momento de enviar una imagen a una api rest conectada con laravel solo me guarda la imagen pero vacia,
Mi codigo en xamarin de la forma que envio la imagen en una

```
var content1 = new MultipartFormDataContent(); 
 content1.Add(new StreamContent(_image.GetStream()), 
             "\"file\"", $"\"{_image.Path}\""); 
  var httpClient1 = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient(); 
  httpClient1.BaseAddress = new Uri("washdryapp.com"); 
  var url1 = "washdryapp.com/app/public/washer/guardar_img"; 
  var responseMsg1 = await httpClient1.PostAsync(url1, content1); 
  var remotePath = await responseMsg1.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); 


  var httpClient2 = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
  var url2 = "http://www.xxxxx.com/oficial/guardar_img";
  var responseMsg2 = await httpClient2.PostAsync(url2, content2);

  var remotePath2 = await responseMsg2.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

lo envio por metodo POST

```
public function storeImg(Request $request) {
    $uploaddir = 'uploads/autos';
    $ext =  $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $filename = $ext;//time().'.'.$ext;
    $upload = $request->file('file')->storeAs(
        'uploads/autos', $filename
    );
    $file_name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
}
```

Gracias

Comment: Falta mucha informacion para saber que te sucede, pusiste tu metodo para enviar a medias. como haces el content2?  porque lees un string cuando devuelve la llamada o que respuesta te da el servidor? que es lo que te pide el servicio en php para enviar o recibir la imagen, lo mandas como un array de bit?

Comment: Disculpa, mi metodo
 var content1 = new MultipartFormDataContent();
                    content1.Add(new StreamContent(_image.GetStream()), "\"file\"", $"\"{_image.Path}\"");

                    var httpClient1 = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
                    httpClient1.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://www.washdryapp.com");
                    var url1 = "http://www.washdryapp.com/app/public/washer/guardar_img";
                    var responseMsg1 = await httpClient1.PostAsync(url1, content1);

                    var remotePath = await responseMsg1.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

Comment: Descubri me guarda un archivo imagen que no es en mi servidor, solo lo abro con un editor de texto, y este contiene la direccion donde se aloja la imagen en el telefono